# Parse DateTime with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, datetime-parsing, localdatetime

I need to parse a date that I receive in a String with the following format: "Mon, 07 Nov 2022 21:00:00 +0100"

I have to dump the date to an object of type LocalDateTime and I use the following code:

```
String fecha = "Mon, 07 Nov 2022 21:00:00 +0100";
    
DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss XXXX");    
LocalDateTime fechaHora = LocalDateTime.parse(fecha, formato);
```

but I get a DateTimeParseException. I can't find the error. Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class here as it lacks an offset from UTC. Your input has an offset.

Comment: The solution is in the accepted answer. For the reason why your code failed, what is your default locale? If it is non-English, this would explain since `Mon` and `Nov` are in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pre-defined format for that: [RFC_1123_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)

```java
String fecha = "Mon, 07 Nov 2022 21:00:00 +0100";
    
DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;    
LocalDateTime fechaHora = LocalDateTime.parse(fecha, formato);
```

Comment: Well spotted. If I want to pick up the offset from the string, as Basil Bourque recommended in a comment, can I parse into an `OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in my local.

However if you want to convert a string to date you can also use SimpleDateFormat

For Ex:

```
String sDate1="Mon, 07 Nov 2022 21:00:00 +0100";  
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ").parse(sDate1);  
System.out.println(date1);
```

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. This is a very discouraged answer. The OP asked for a `LocalDateTime`. I recommend that no one uses the old and poorly designed `Date` class anymore. So please do not suggest it, especially not here. And even if someone wanted an old-fashioned `Date`, don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, it is notoriously troublesome.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
will make sure to provide reliable and efficient answers going forward